# AWS Simple DB Management Tool

Tags: amazon-simpledb

I'm using Amazon SimpleDB for my web application. I'm looking for a tool like phpMyAdmin that will allow me to administer the database from one place (see all my Domains, view all records - run test queries etc) but all I can find is the free firefox plugin from Bizo

```
http://dev.bizo.com/2008/12/open-source-simple-db-firefox-plugin.html
```

This will not do because it wont let me point it at the European host of simple DB which is sdb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

I don't mind paying for something if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

I use SDB Explorer (http://www.sdbexplorer.com/), which is not free, but reasonably priced.

Answer (score 5):

Useful tools for SDB:

SDBTool (Firefox Extension):
http://code.google.com/p/sdbtool/

SDBNavigator (Chrome Extension):
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sdbnavigator/ddhigekdfabonefhiildaiccafacphgg

SDB Explorer:
http://www.sdbexplorer.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've just installed the bizo.com SDB Firefox extension and I can select the EU region from the dropdown on the lower left of the screen.

I have version 2010-05-03.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Eclipse user, the [AWS Toolkit for Eclipse](http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse) includes Amazon SimpleDB support, as well as a number of other AWS services.